# Cannot overwrite __contains__ with a lambda

Tags: python

I would like to create a class can be used in `in` statements, and the condition is passed to the object in `__init__`. An example:

```py
class Set:
    def __init__(self, contains):
        self.__contains__ = contains  # or setattr; doesn't matter

top = Set(lambda _: True)
bottom = Set(lambda _: False)
```

The problem with this is that `3 in top` returns `TypeError: argument of type 'Set' is not iterable`, even though `top.__contains__(3)` returns `True` as expected.

What's more, if I modify the code as such:

```py
class Set:
    def __init__(self, contains):
        self.__contains__ = contains

    def __contains__(self, x):
        return False

top = Set(lambda _: True)
```

, `3 in top` will return `False`, whereas `top.__contains__(3)` returns `True` as expected, again.

What is happening here? I am on Python 3.9.2.

(Note: the same happens with other methods that are part of the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), such as `__gt__`, `__eq__` , etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because magic methods are looked up on the class, not the instance. The interpreter circumvents the usual attribute-getting mechanisms when performing "overloadable" operations.

It seems to be this way because of how it was originally implemented in CPython, for example because of how [type slots](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#type-objects) work (not the `__slots__` slots, that's a different thing): how `+` or `*` or other operators works on a value is decided by its class, not on per instance basis.

There's a performance benefit to this: looking up a dunder method can involve a dictionary lookup, or worse, some dynamic computations with `__getattr__`/`__getattribute__`. However, I don't know if this is the main reason it is this way.

I wasn't able to find a detailed written description, but there's [a talk by Armin Ronacher on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCGofLIzX6g) going quite in depth on this.

Comment: Thanks, that explains what I saw. I can still make `Set` work then, but it will be uglier. :(

Comment: Now you can create a set of all sets that don't contain themselves :) `russell = Set(lambda x: x not in x); print(russell in russell)`

Answer (score 1):

`__contains__` is an instance method that takes a `self` arg.

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.\_\_contains\_\](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.%5C_%5C_contains%5C_%5C)_

> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`

So I think what is happening in each case is:

1. > The problem with this is that `3 in top` returns `TypeError: argument of type 'Set' is not iterable`, even though `top.__contains__(3)` returns `True` as expected.

```py
class Set:
    def __init__(self, contains):
        self.__contains__ = contains  # or setattr; doesn't matter

top = Set(lambda _: True)
```

You `Set` *class* doesn't have a `__contains__` method, only the instance has it. So Python doesn't recognise Set objects as implementing this protocol, so it falls back to trying the search approach via `__iter__`... but your Set class is not iterable.

2. > `3 in top` will return `False`, whereas `top.__contains__(3)` returns `True` as expected, again.

```py
class Set:
    def __init__(self, contains):
        self.__contains__ = contains

    def __contains__(self, x):
        return False

top = Set(lambda _: True)
```

This time your Set class does have the `__contains__` method, so Python will try to use it. We can see from the behaviour that `3 in top` is different from `top.__contains__(3)`.  What actually happens for `3 in top` is Python does something like `Set.__contains__(top, 3)`

So depending how you call it you get either the method on the class, or the lambda you overrode on the instance.

Comment: Yes, but the question was why. :) @decorator-factory, above, linked a video explaining the inner workings in detail.

Comment: the question you wrote was "what?" rather than "why?", but no prob